# Java non-greedy (?) regex to match string

Tags: java, regex

```
String poolId = "something/something-else/pools[name='test'][scope='lan1']";
String statId = "something/something-else/pools[name='test'][scope='lan1']/stats[base-string='10.10.10.10']";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+pools\\[name='.+'\\]\\[scope='.+'\\]$");
```

What regular expression should be used such that

```
pattern.matcher(poolId).matches()
```

returns `true` whereas

```
pattern.matcher(statsId).matches()
```

returns `false`?

Note that

1. `something/something-else` is irrelevant and can be of any length
2. Both `name` and `scope` can have ANY character including any of `\, /, [, ]` etc
3. `stats[base-string='10.10.10.10']` is an example and there can be anything else after `/`

I tried to use the non-greedy `?` like so `.+pools\\[name='.+'\\]\\[scope='.+?'\\]$` but still both matches return `true`

Comment: The issue is that your lazy capture is capturing the ending single quote from base-string.

Comment: When you say "Both `name` and `scope` can have ANY character, do you mean their key (literally "name") or their value?

Comment: I have never been able to understand why programmers want to mess around with greedy vs. non-greedy matching when you can just express directly in regular expression syntax, "one or more (or zero or more) characters that are not the closing delimiter". Can name and scope really contain a single quote? Is that an important use case? If so, and you need to be able to handle escaped single quotes, then it is not a regular expression and you should be using a parser.

Comment: @DavidConrad, I've edited the question to reflect that the closing delimiter `'` cannot be included in the name and scope I've realized from Jakob's answer below the problem in allowing that and your point that a parser would be needed in that case. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```java
.+pools\[name='[^']*'\]\[scope='[^']*'\]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sf0IVA/1). *Details*:

- `.+` - any one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `pools\[name='` - a `pools[name='`string
- `[^']*` - zero or more chars other than a `'`
- `'\]\[scope='` - a `'][scope='` string
- `[^']*` - zero or more chars other than a `'`
- `'\]` - a `']` substring
- `$` -  end of string.

In Java:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+pools\\[name='[^']*']\\[scope='[^']*']$");
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/jb9nun):

```java
//String s = "something/something-else/pools[name='test'][scope='lan1']"; // => Matched!
String s = "something/something-else/pools[name='test'][scope='lan1']/stats[base-string='10.10.10.10']";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+pools\\[name='[^']*']\\[scope='[^']*']$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("Matched!"); 
} else {
    System.out.println("Not Matched!"); 
}
// => Not Matched!
```

Answer (score 2):

Wiktor assumed that your values for `name` and `scope` cannot have single quotes in them. Thus the following:

```
.../pools[name='tes't']
```

would not match. This is really the only valid assumption to make, as if you can include unescaped single quotes, then what's to stop the value of `scope` from being (for example) the literal value `lan1']/stats[base-string='10.10.10.10`? The regex you included in your question has this issue. If you simply must have these values in your code, you need to escape them somehow. Try the following (edit of Wiktor's regex):

```
.+pools\[name='([^']|\\')*'\]\[scope='([^']|\\')*'\]$
```